# NestJS gRPC route 404

Tags: angular, grpc, nestjs

I'm using the NestJS gRPC tutorial project:

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/04-grpc/

[hero.proto](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/04-grpc/src/hero/hero.proto) file contents:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package hero;

service HeroService {
  rpc FindOne (HeroById) returns (Hero) {}
}

message HeroById {
  int32 id = 1;
}

message Hero {
  int32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
}
```

From what I understand, defines the path as:

```
/hero.HeroService/FindOne
```

[hero.controller.ts](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/04-grpc/src/hero/hero.controller.ts) contents:

```
@Controller()
export class HeroController implements OnModuleInit {
  @GrpcMethod('HeroService')
  findOne(data: HeroById): Hero {
    const items: Hero[] = [{ id: 1, name: 'John' }, { id: 2, name: 'Doe' }];
    return items.find(({ id }) => id === data.id);
  }
}
```

Which in theory should expose the method at:

```
http://localhost:3001/hero.HeroService/FindOne
```

But when called, produces this error:

> error: "Not Found" message: "Cannot POST /hero.HeroService/FindOne"
>   statusCode: 404

I know i'm hitting NestJS because I have middleware logging. If I hit a GET route it works and returns the correct data, but GRPC routes are all 404s. What am I missing?

I've tried `@Controller('hero')` instead to try prefixing the path. It doesn't seem easy to have NestJS log out all of the gRPC endpoints for me to debug...

Full project source code is here:

https://github.com/kmturley/angular-nest-grpc

------ UPDATE -------

Installed grpc_cli using:

```
brew tap grpc/grpc
brew install --with-plugins grpc
```

Then tried to view the endpoints using:

```
export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
grpc_cli ls localhost:3001
```

And got the error:

> Received an error when querying services endpoint.

Or using:

```
grpc_cli call localhost:3001 FindOne "id: 1" --protofiles=src/hero/hero.proto
```

I get the error:

```
ServerReflectionInfo rpc failed. Error code: 14, details: OS Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by adding an additional line to grpc-client.options.ts to define the url:

```
export const grpcClientOptions: ClientOptions = {
  transport: Transport.GRPC,
  options: {
    url: 'localhost:50051',
    package: 'hero',
    protoPath: join(__dirname, './hero/hero.proto'),
  },
};
```

Then I could connect to it on that port using:

```
grpc_cli call localhost:50051 FindOne "id: 1" --protofiles=backend/src/hero/hero.proto
```

You can see it working here:

https://github.com/kmturley/angular-nest-grpc

Answer (score 0):

the default port of grpc transport is `5000` in nestjs, see https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/v6.10.14/packages/microservices/constants.ts#L8